# Iterating polygons in folder as input in QGIS Modeler like ArcGIS ModelBuilder

Tags: qgis, iterator, qgis-modeler

How do I iterate polygons in a folder as input in QGIS modeller?

Usually, ArcGIS can iterate polygons as an input for functions like union, merge, intersect, etc.

But I cannot find the way to do this in QGIS modeller, not a pyqgis (for convenience).

Comment: [[more questions]]

Comment: if iterate possible, how to set the output name as input file name? like %name% or %value% in ARCGIS MODELER

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176599/simplify-repetitive-tasks-in-qgis-graphical-modeler. Have a look at the comments under the answer as well.